# Multiple threads in on class

Tags: java, multithreading, multitasking

I'm trying to create two classes that extends from Thread, I know how to create one class.

```
public class Main {
  class Thred1 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("I'm watching a video...");
    }
  }
  
  class Thred2 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("I'm eating...");
    }
  }
  
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Thred1 t11 = new Thred1();
    Thred2 t12 = new Thred2();
    t11.start();
    t12.start();
  }
}
```

And got `Main.java:15: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`

Is there better way to implement my idea?

Comment: Your classes have to be static inner classes. `static class Thred1 extends Thread {` and so on. In general, I would advise you to stay away from inner classes and instead give each class its own file. That simplifies things a lot, if you are a beginner.

Comment: And just saying: this is very basic **syntax** stuff. Threading and concurrency is an advanced topic. Consider to really master the basics first, before starting on an advanced topic like Threads.

Comment: And in general, you should not use `extends Thread`, but instead implement `Runnable` and pass an instance to `new Thread(yourRunnable)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with inner classes and not with threads , try to put all this code in the same file `Main.java` :

```java
class Thred1 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I'm watching a video...");
    }
}
          
class Thred2 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I'm eating...");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Thred1 t11 = new Thred1();
        Thred2 t12 = new Thred2();
        t11.start();
        t12.start();
    }
}
```

Another possible solution is to use *static classes* instead of the *member inner classes* used in your code :

```
public class Main {
    static class Thred1 extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("I'm watching a video...");
        }
    }

    static class Thred2 extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("I'm eating...");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thred1 t11 = new Thred1();
        Thred2 t12 = new Thred2();
        t11.start();
        t12.start();
    }
}
```

Or simply you can use **Lambda** expression , *Thread* class have a constructor who accept a *Runnable* as parameter , *Runnable* is a functional interface so you can pass a **Lambda** expression as argument like that :

```
public class Main {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t11 = new Thread(()->System.out.println("I'm watching a video..."));
        Thread t12 = new Thread(()->System.out.println("I'm eating..."));
        t11.start();
        t12.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to give answers that give ALL the relevant options. Such as: simply making those inner classes static.

Comment: Okay ,i will try to update it